# How does magic power affect buffing spells in Demon's Souls

Tags: demons-souls

How are various shielding spells in demon's souls affected by increasing the Magic skill (not intelligence). Duration? Shielding effect? Amount of MP spent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic has no affect on defensive spells such as Protection, Warding, and Water Veil.